# I have file with with 3 lines as follows. Using linux how can i get the split variables of a line and append it to the same line

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Using linux, how can I get the below desired output for the given Input. 
Input file:

```
Line1: StringA1, stringB1| stringC1, stringD1, stringE1
Line2: StringA2, stringB2| stringC2, stringD2
Line3: StringA3, stringB3| stringC3, stringD3, stringE3, stringF3
```

My output should be:

```
StringA1, stringB1| stringC1
StringA1, stringB1| stringD1
StringA1, stringB1| stringE1
StringA2, stringB2| stringC2
StringA2, stringB2| stringD2
StringA3, stringB3| stringC3
StringA3, stringB3| stringD3
StringA3, stringB3| stringE3
StringA3, stringB3| stringF3
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your post so it's easier to read and figure out what you want?

Comment: `cut` could do that.  `awk` as well.  Try something, then we can help.

Comment: When you don't know where to start, you can explain which options you considered, like: "I don't know how to process the substrings I found after using `cut` on field delim `|` or on ','. Perhaps `awk` is possible, but for me that is a complete new tool. The best option I could thing of is using a `while loop`, processing one line at a time. I have read, that using a `while loop` gives a bad performance. Now I am stuck, what should I do?"

Comment: You mention `linux`, where `bash` is the default shell. Why do you want `ksh` ?

Comment: does the input file contain the strings `Line1: / Line2: / Line3:`?  Alternatively, what is the exact output from `cat <input_file_name>`?

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- all lines have at least 3 fields
- the lines do not contain the string `Line#:` (otherwise we just need to modify the proposed script)

Sample data:

```
$ cat strings.dat
StringA1, stringB1| stringC1, stringD1, stringE1
StringA2, stringB2| stringC2, stringD2
StringA3, stringB3| stringC3, stringD3, stringE3, stringF3
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F"[,|]" '
{ for ( i=3;i<=NF;i++ )
      { printf "%s,%s|%s\n", $1, $2, $i }
}' strings.dat
```

Where:

- `-F"[,|]"` - use comma and pipe (`,|`) as input delimiters
- `for ( i=3;i<=NF;i++ )` - for fields 3 to end of line (NF == number of fields == last field)
- `{ printf ... }` - print 1st, 2nd and `ith` fields

Results of running the above:

```
StringA1, stringB1| stringC1
StringA1, stringB1| stringD1
StringA1, stringB1| stringE1
StringA2, stringB2| stringC2
StringA2, stringB2| stringD2
StringA3, stringB3| stringC3
StringA3, stringB3| stringD3
StringA3, stringB3| stringE3
StringA3, stringB3| stringF3
```

Comment: **note:** you still need to split *field1*, your command provides output of `"Line1: StringA1,  stringB1|  stringC1"`, etc.. (though the remainder of your approach is correct so it still warrants the UV. It appears the issue here was an oversight.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin see my assumptions (no 'Line#:' in the actual file), my data file (`cat strings.dat`) and my comment/question to the OP re: 'Line#:' in the file; it's not clear (to me) if the strings 'Line#:' are part of the file or the OP just labeling the lines in the question; if the OP comes back and says 'Line#:' is in the file then that's easy enough to parse out

Comment: Gotcha, I did read your assumptions, but didn't snap to it when I ran the output. He's covered either way at this point.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a solution in `sed`, it will become hard to read and hard to maintain:

```
sed -E 's/,/\v/; :a; s/(.*\|)(.*),(.*)$/\1\2\r\1\3/;ta; s/\v/,/g;s/\r/\n/g' inputfile
```

**Explanation:**
`s/,/\v/` Most `,` should be replaced, but not the one in the replacement string.
`:a` Repeat next command (until `ta`) while a replacement is found.
`(.*\|)(.*),(.*)$` Match 3 substrings: The starter, the middle part util the last `,` and the end part.
`\r` Use the windows CR as a marker where we want a newline when finished.
`\1` Replace with the first remembered string (in example `StringA1, stringB1`).
`/\1\2\r\1\3/` Replace the last `,` with a newline marker and the starter.
`ta;` Repeat until all replacements are done.
`s/\v/,/g;` Restore the `,` characters.
`s/\r/\n/g'` Replace new line marker with a real newline.

Other ways are using `awk` and a `while loop`. For a large file I recommand `awk`, perhaps you want to try this yourself before someone posts an answer.

Comment: Now that is an interesting use of `sed` for the problem. While the `awk` approach is likely the tool for the job, the use of `sed` here (along with the good explanation) certainly warrants the UV.

Comment: **note:** you still need to split *field1*, your command provides output of `"Line1: StringA1,  stringB1|  stringC1"`, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I made the same assumption that markp did, testing with `echo "StringA1, stringB1| stringC1, stringD1, stringE1" | sed ....`. Adding 's/[^:]: //' can help when needed.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Really strange to have the lines in the question with the ambiguous Line at the front that looks like it may/may not be in the file. Oh well. He is covered. Again, good job using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce your desired output, if you are splitting on `[,|]`, you must further remove the beginning of *field1* before outputting the results. There are two ways I see to do that. The first way simply splits *field1* into an array with the *fieldsep* of `' '`, the second is with a combination of `substr, match & length`. The first is the simple way of doing it using the `split()` command, e.g.

```
awk -F '[,|]' '{
    split ($1, arr, / /)
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s,%s|%s\n", arr[2], $2, $i
    }
}' file
```

For the second, you can remove `split()` above and replace `arr[2]` with:

```
substr($1,match($1,/ /)+1,length($1)-match($1,/ /))
```

If your data file does not include `"Line[0-9]: "` as the prefix for each line, you can include the following as your `printf` to handle either case:

```
printf "%s,%s|%s\n", arr[2]=="" ? arr[1] : arr[2], $2, $i
```

The results are the same either way, but using `split()` would be the recommended way.

**Example Use/Output**

Using the proposed `awk` solution with your data file (named `file` adjust as needed), you can just select-copy/middle-mouse-paste in an xterm with the `file` in the current directory to obtain the results, e.g.

```
$ awk -F '[,|]' '{
>     split ($1, arr, / /)
>     for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
>         printf "%s,%s|%s\n", arr[2], $2, $i
>     }
> }' file
StringA1, stringB1| stringC1
StringA1, stringB1| stringD1
StringA1, stringB1| stringE1
StringA2, stringB2| stringC2
StringA2, stringB2| stringD2
StringA3, stringB3| stringC3
StringA3, stringB3| stringD3
StringA3, stringB3| stringE3
StringA3, stringB3| stringF3
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: or add `:` as an additional input delimiter and process fields 2, 3 and 4-NF